# Not all request parameters showing ajax node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am building an app using node.js and have a GET endpoint in the form:

`/api/car/:id`

I have a GET request like:

```
var data = {
    color: 'red',
    mileage: '1000'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/car/12345",
    data: {color: 'red', mileage: '1000'},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('some error occurred');
    }
});
```

When I console.log the parameters on the server side I only get the '12345' but I do not get the parameters defined in `data`:

`console.log(req.params)`

`{ id: '12345' }`

Whereas it should be something like:

`{ id: '12345', color: 'red', mileage: '1000' }`

Can someone help? I need to use all 3 parameters on the server side...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Express.

Query string data (which is where jQuery will put the values you pass to `data` when you make a GET request) is found in [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), not [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) (which only contains the parameters defined in your route specification).

Comment: perfect!! *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

`req.params` returns parameters matched in your defined route. To access the parameters sent in the query string part of the url, you need to use `req.query`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the color with req.body.color.
But first you need a "body-parser" package.

Comment: No, you can't. It is a GET request, the data isn't in the body.

Comment: Oh yach i didn't saw the verb.